# Scope is undefined after getting results from a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to traverse the data I get from a service into a scope in my controller, but I can't get the last step right (I think). I added steps to see if perhaps inserting the data into the scope happens before the actual request from the service, but that's not the case.

Step 1: I activate the addMovie function in the controller.
Step 2: I create an empty movieListID scope.

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  console.log ('Step 1: start addMovie function in controller')
  console.log ('Step 2: create empty movieListID scope')
  $scope.movieListID = {};
  console.log ($scope.movieListID)

  movieAdd.add()
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.movieListID = response;
      console.log ('Step 4: Succes inserting data into scope' + $scope.movieListID)
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.log ('No search reposone')
    });
}
```

Step 3: Get the data from the service.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movieAdd',

    function($http, $q){
      return{
        add: function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
          // Search for release dates using the ID.
          var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
          var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
          var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
          var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
          var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
          var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

          $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              if (status == 200) {

                deferred.resolve(data.results);
                console.log ('Step 3: Succes getting data')

              } else {
                console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              }

            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              deferred.resolve(false);
            });

            $(".search_results").fadeOut(250);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    })

})();
```

Step 4:

```
movieAdd.add()
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.movieListID = response;
    console.log ('Step 4: Succes inserting data into scope' + $scope.movieListID)
```

But when I get to step 4 I get a "undefined" returned in the console log, which refers to the `$scope.movieListID`

Also if I check the network tab in Chrome I see that the json request has been done. So the data is inside the service. But getting it into the scope is not working.

Comment: First thought, are you injecting the service into your controller?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would be recieving provider errors.

Comment: Are you sure that your data is data.results?  Try to console there response from server.

Comment: @Errorpro Hm! When I  did `console.log (data.results)` it returned empty, but just `data` returned the desired object! And changing to just `data` in the controller gives me the `not empty` message! Thanks! Never would have thought of it.

Comment: you're welcome. Point my answer as correct to help other people find it easy. good luck.

Comment: Isn't it better if you create the answer and I check it?